# How can I propagate an identity from an asp.net mvc application in order to access a tfs server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, tfs, asp.net-identity

I am developing an asp.net mvc application to extract some data from a TFS server.

Right now I am having problems with authentication on the TFS server. When I run the app from my local machine everything works fine, since it propagates my windows identity to the server, but when I deploy the app to my IIS8 server, since there's no user logged on, it won't work.

I would like to avoid using windows authentication on the IIS8 server, since I do not want to maintain the user control with windows groups. Instead I would like only to authenticate the user on my AD, store the identity info and propagate it to the TFS server, but I am clueless on how to do that.

Can you guys help me out? Right now my asp.net mvc app has no authentication and I get the following message:

```
    [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio' is denied.]
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str) +4325774
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions) +10872754
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistryOptions options) +14
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorageHelper.GetRootKey(String subkeyName) +50
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorage.RetrieveToken(VssTokenKey tokenKey) +57
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.VssTokenStorage.Retrieve(VssTokenKey tokenKey) +15
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentialStorage.RetrieveToken(Uri serverUrl, VssCredentialsType credentialType) +58
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CookieCredential.OnCreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response) +127
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.IssuedTokenCredential.CreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response, IssuedToken failedToken) +45
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials.TryGetTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IssuedTokenProvider& provider) +95
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.PrepareWebRequest(HttpWebRequest webRequest, Guid sessionId, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider) +136
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.CreateSoapRequest(Uri requestUri, Guid sessionId, String soapAction, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider) +106
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.CreateWebRequest() +154
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest() +599
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout) +243
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs) +91
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32 connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, Int32 features) +175
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions connectOptions) +92
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected() +723
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated() +25
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that your need to make the account that the website is running under an administrator on your web server. Current permissions are not going to cut the mustered.

Additionally you are going to hit a double hop authentication issue with Kerberos ( security is a pain) and you need to configure an SPN for the account to show it to proxy Kerberos authentication tokens to the TFS server. User SetSPN to configure it, and you will likely need the help of a domain admin.